# Zend Framework: Extend Zend_Form to add default Form elements?

Tags: zend-framework

i have created my own Zend_Form class currently just to add some helper functions and setdefault decorators.

now what i want to do is add some defaults (`setMethod('post')`) and add some elements (if u know the honeypot method to prevent spam bots.) how do i do it? in the `__construct()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite the contructor should be fine.

```
class Your_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        $this->setMethod('POST');
        $this->addElement('hidden', 'hash', array('ignore' => true));
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
```

So your other Forms can extend `Your_Form` and call `init()`, so it stays consistent.

```
class Model_Form_Login extends Your_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
         $this->addElement('input', 'username');
         ...
```

If you overwrite the init()-Method you don't have to call the parent::__construct()...

```
class Your_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('POST');
        $this->addElement('hidden', 'hash', array('ignore' => true));

    }
```

... but all your extending Forms have to call parent::init() like so

```
class Model_Form_Login extends Your_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
         $this->addElement('input', 'username');
         ...
         parent::init();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you will read the `__construct` of `Zend_Form` you will see it is calling the empty method `init()`.
So you have two choices:

1. create your own construct and **do not** forget to call the parent construct
2. (recommended) put what ever you want in the `init()` method. That way you will be sure that everything was instantiated correctly.

the `init()` is something consistent to the entire framework (which ever class you want to extend).

```
class My_Super_Form extends Zend_Form{
   protected function init(){
     //here I do what ever I want, and I am sure it will be called in the instantiation.
   }
}
```

Comment: the reason why i think of using the construct is because i want to create an "abstract" zend form class (reusability) where all my other forms will extend. i mannaged to make it work with `__construct()` and i called `parent::construct()` at the start too

Comment: create the abstract which will inherit the Zend_Form and you inherit the abstract. The only reason for that is that each upgrade of the system you will have to touch the library if you do that. (or I did not understand what you did).